# mysql select join 4 tables

Tags: mysql, join, select

Anyone can help me to make query as image below? Need your help guys.

I describe it by image. Hope you all can understand my problem.

My query i have done..

```
select A.ticket_id,A.number,B.subject,C.value as service,C.value as vendor,C.value as category,C.value as action
from tableA A
left join tableB B ON A.ticket_id = B.ticket_id
left join tableD C ON C.id = B.vendor
where A.ticket_id = 28 or A.ticket_id = 36 or A.ticket_id = 149;
```

the problem is service,vendor,category & action refer to same field = C.value

How to solved this issue?

[image: join 4 tables]

Thanks

Comment: I am tempted to say "You hum it, we will play it" By that I mean you must be able to at least start coding this to JOIN at least a few of these tables. You will always get a better response on this site if you can show you have made some effort to solve your own problem

Comment: You will have to make a new JOIN for each of those conditions. As if they were in different tables even though they are in the same table

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Google 'stackexchange notifications' to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment.

Comment: You don't explain how output is a function of input or give an example so how can we help you other than by guessing? Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the below query and see if you get desired values

```
SELECT A.ticket_id,A.number,B.subject,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT C3.value) as service,C.value as vendor,C1.value as category,C2.value as action
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.ticket_id = B.ticket_id
LEFT JOIN tableD C ON C.id = B.vendor
LEFT JOIN tableD C1 ON C1.id = B.category
LEFT JOIN tableD C2 ON C2.id = B.action
LEFT JOIN tableD C3 ON FIND_IN_SET(C3.id,B.service) > 0
WHERE A.ticket_id IN (28,36,149)
GROUP BY A.ticket_id
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, got desire values, but only problem with "service" field because consist 2 id = 26 & 27

Comment: same result.. service id = 27 not appear

Comment: I have attached the screenshot that shows my query is working properly.